# How to load one csv in multiple tables with R

Tags: r

I'm working with a set of data that have multiple headers:

```
Lap 1   Athlete   Speed   Distance
        Player 01 5       767
        Player 02 9       886
        Player 03 19      981
Lap 2   Athlete   Speed   Distance
        Player 01 7       876
        Player 02 6       454
        Player 03 14      998
Lap 3   Athlete   Speed   Distance
        Player 01 8       097
        Player 02 9       556
        Player 03 7       453
```

Within RStudio, I want to split these data. Here is my code:

```
setwd("E:/Data/R/M1UltimateAnalysis")
DATA_SET_MAIN <- read.csv2("data/dataset.csv", header = FALSE)

DATA_SET_LAPS = split(DATA_SET_MAIN,
                      sample(rep(1:3,4)))

DATA_SET_LAP_1 = DATA_SET_LAPS$`1`
write.csv(DATA_SET_LAP_1,
          file="First_lap.csv",
          quote = F,
          row.names = F)
```

But the split is ordered in something quite random and without any header.

How can I do that in R?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the sample function, which in this case is scrambling the `rep(1:3,4)`, this is assigning random row numbers for the split function to use in sorting.

First you will need to remove the lines with headers in.
You can use this as headers first
`names(DATA_SET_MAIN) <- as.character(DATA_SET_MAIN[1,])
 DATA_SET_MAIN <- DATA_SET_MAIN[DATA_SET_MAIN[,1] == '', ]`

You can then remove the first column:

```
DATA_SET_MAIN[,1] <- NULL
```

Then you can use the split function

```
DATA_SET_LAPS = split(DATA_SET_MAIN,
                  rep(1:3,each = 3))
```